# How to replace char* using smart pointers?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have to expose an API which takes a char* as input argument. The char* points to a chunk of binary data on heap. In this case the caller have to manage the memory allocation and deletion.

Is there a way that I could use a shared_ptr as input argument instead of a raw pointer.

```
void func(char* data)
{
   //some operation
}
```

Comment: What stops the user from saying `char x[100]; func(x);`?  There is no heap involvement there.  Maybe your `func` function shouldn't do too much hand-holding -- let the caller handle the memory.

Comment: Is `func` going to participate in the ownership of the pointer or is it just viewing it's contents?

Comment: That is up to the caller, it may be on stack or heap but can I use a smart pointer instead of raw pointer

Comment: @NathanOliver it is going to view and doesn't own

Comment: @Deepak If it isn't going to participate in ownership then accepting a raw pointer is fine.  Just don't hold on to it for later or pass it up out of the scope of the thing that does own it.

Comment: I think it's not possible to use a smart pointer at this place. A shared pointer counts owners and whe the number of owners gets to zero (at end of your function) the memory is freed. So your function would delete memory that should be managed from outside

Comment: 1. It looks to me like it is not clear to you who must own the data. 2. Don't use `std` in API. If you use it, you must be sure the client is using the same 'std' library & compiler.

Comment: It depends on circumstances but I would be tempted to use `std::vector<char> const& data` because something has to own that data and containers are usually preferable. I would also be tempted to use `std::byte` rather than `char` for binary data.

Answer (score 1):

If `func` simply observes the data without changing it, have it accept a `const char *`. The caller can store the pointer in any smart pointer, and use the `get()` function to get a bare pointer to pass to `func`.

If `func` changes the data, I like to steal ideas from Rust and pass in a `std::unique_ptr` and return a `std::unique_ptr`. The caller passes away ownership and then receives back ownership of a pointer, but possibly a completely different pointer. And it doesn't matter.

If `func` has to modify the data and it has to accept a `char *` then just use `get()` as before from any smart pointer that you want. As long as `func` does not store the pointer somewhere nothing will break.

Comment: The problem with giving up ownership and taking it back is that makes it hard to have exception-safe code. If your function throws, that object is hard to recover.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I've never needed to recover an object in that situation, but I suppose you have a point. In my cases it would just get thrown away anyway.